# How to rename widget ID's in Eclipse?

Tags: android, refactoring, rename

I am working on an app built upon an example from a tutorial. Now the different widget IDs no longer reflect their purpose so I would like to rename them. However, this seems quite a task as the IDs are used in multiple files.

Is it possible somehow to rename the IDs so the changes are migrated into the other files in the project? That is pretty much similar to refactor source code names, but for widget IDs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think a tool like that exists in Eclipse.  The easiest way to do it manually is to rename an item in the XML layout and then track down the errors in the Java classes.  If you do it one-by-one then you should have it cleaned up in a minute or two.

Comment: This is what I intented, and it works. Eclipse will point me to the right places where I need to rename. This in combination with simple search&replace as suggested by Brendon works acceptable.

Answer (score 3):

You can try to use the Find/Replace function is Eclipse. I have found this useful several times when changing ID's or something to that effect. Let us know what you end up doing.

Comment: This is working for me right now but really unfortunate you can't refactor + rename. Quite frustrating really.

Answer (score 1):

In eclipse:

Go to the xml layout `-> Graphical Layout -> Properties` then click the `...` button near the desired field:

[image: refactor_widget]

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone stumbles across this problem now, you can rename the ID from the visual layout editor and it will do all the hard work automatically.